# To discuss differentiability of function at origin and my attempt

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

P1:  $F =  |x| +  |y|  when x,y is not equal to 0,

```
  =   0   when x = y = 0
```

P2 :Discuss the differentiability at origin  of  $F = y sin(1/x)$
 :[image: FOR P1]

[image]

[image: FOR P2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near good, but for $|x|+|y|$. Do not use argument, that partial derivatives are not continuous. Theorem says "if partial derivatives... are continuous... derivative exists", but not reverse. However argument with one sided partial derivatives in enough.

For the corrected version of P2 ($f(x,y)=y\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq0$ and 0 for $x=0$):
$$
f'_y(0,0)=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{0-0}{y}=0,\quad
f'_x(0,0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{0\sin(1/x)-0}{x}=0,
$$
hence (in case P2) partial derivatives exist.

Function $f$ is differentiable in $(x_0,y_0)$ if
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x_0+h,y_0+k)-f(x_0,y_0)-f'_x(x_0,y_0)h-f'_y(x_0,y_0)k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0.
$$
In our case we obtain
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{k\sin(1/h)-0-0-0}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}.
$$
Let $k=h$. Then
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h\sin(1/h)}{\sqrt{2h^2}},
$$
which doesn't exist.

*Edit:* I can see, that there is yet another definition of $f$ ($f(0,y) = y$). Then $f'_y(0,0)=1$ and modifications are the following:
$$
\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{k\sin(1/h)-0-0-k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}.
$$
Let $k=h$. Then
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h(\sin(1/h)-1)}{\sqrt{2h^2}},
$$
which again doesn't exist.

Phew!

Comment: Then how i am to conclude for differentiabilty . i mean what i have shown isnt that enough for differentiation .

Comment: What about P2 Then?

Comment: @godonichia But how is $F$ in P2 defined for $x=0$? If undefined, there is nothing to do. If F(0,y)=0$, your calculations of partial derivative are wrong.

Comment: its defined in latter way u said .can u pls clarify more

Comment: @godonichia In your notes you have $f(x,y)=0$ but only for $(0,0)$. If really, it is undefined on any disc with center at origin, hence there is nothing to do (with the standard definition of differentiability).

Comment: ok i see now . it was my mistake it is f(0,y) = y

Comment: thanks for answer . th emethod u have shown for function to be differentiable . in that you have let h=k and let h goes to zero and converted into 1 variable limit q. will that method APPLY TO EVERY QUESTION  to test for differentiability ( i mean not method but letting h=k stuff)

Comment: @godonichia No, when we want to show, that the limit doesn't exist, we can find two paths with different limits. Here situation is relatively easy, because $\sin(1/x)$ spoils the limit, hence taking $h=k$ is a simple method to reducing the problem to a one-dimensional one. In general, finding two paths (or two sequences) with  different limits may be a challenge. I am assuming, that there is a typo in your comment and you know, that there was shown, that derivative **does not**exist.

Comment: thanks you have helped me a lot in making my concepts clear .tons  of thanks and gratitude for you

Answer (score -1):

For the first question, your answer is wrong. The limits you've given do exist at the origin, the problem is that they come to different numbers depending on the direction. Thus the derivative is not well-defined.

Comment: Isn't it same as saying partial f wrt x and y doesnt exist at origin.

Comment: You need to explicitly show that the limit is different depending on the direction, not just state the conclusion.